# Create a view/temporary table from a column with CSV

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comma Separated values in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627916/comma-separated-values-in-oracle)

Folks, I know its an exteremly bad idea, and this table needs to be normalized. But unfortunately I cannot change the schema.

We have a table in Oracle DB , as

```
id|value   | other_columns
----------------------------
 1|a,b,c   |some values
```

Can we create a view  with something like

```
id|value   
-----------
 1|a
 1|b
 1|c
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: What version of Oracle?  11g introduces PIVOT, but with your values in a single column I am not certain that will get you all the way to where you want to go.

Comment: Not a dupe, that question wanted a procedure to split column values. This post wants a view.

Comment: You say you can't change the schema, does that include adding a table and triggers to keep it in synch with the oprginal table? It would perform better to do the splitting only once each time the field is updated than every time you need to view the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is an exact duplicate of the question referenced in the close votes. Similar yes, but not the same.

Not exactly beautiful, but:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW your_view AS
SELECT tt.ID, SUBSTR(value, sp, ep-sp) split, other_col1, other_col2...
  FROM (SELECT id, value
             , INSTR(','||value, ',', 1, L) sp  -- 1st posn of substr at this level
             , INSTR(value||',', ',', 1, L) ep  -- posn of delimiter at this level
          FROM tt JOIN (SELECT LEVEL L FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 20) q -- 20 is max #substrings
                    ON LENGTH(value)-LENGTH(REPLACE(value,','))+1 >= L 
) qq JOIN tt on qq.id = tt.id;
```

where tt is your table.

Works for csv values longer than 1 or null. The CONNECT BY LEVEL < 20 is arbitrary, adjust for your situation.

To illustrate:

```
    SQL> CREATE TABLE tt (ID INTEGER, c VARCHAR2(20), othercol VARCHAR2(20));

    Table created
    SQL> INSERT INTO tt VALUES (1, 'a,b,c', 'val1');

    1 row inserted
    SQL> INSERT INTO tt VALUES (2, 'd,e,f,g', 'val2');

    1 row inserted
    SQL> INSERT INTO tt VALUES (3, 'a,f', 'val3');

    1 row inserted
    SQL> INSERT INTO tt VALUES (4,'aa,bbb,cccc', 'val4');

    1 row inserted
    SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myview AS
      2  SELECT tt.ID, SUBSTR(c, sp, ep-sp+1) splitval, othercol
      3    FROM (SELECT ID
      4               , INSTR(','||c,',',1,L) sp, INSTR(c||',',',',1,L)-1 ep
      5            FROM tt JOIN (SELECT LEVEL L FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 20) q
      6                      ON LENGTH(c)-LENGTH(REPLACE(c,','))+1 >= L
      7  ) q JOIN tt ON q.id =tt.id;

    View created
    SQL> select * from myview order by 1,2;

                                     ID SPLITVAL             OTHERCOL
--------------------------------------- -------------------- --------------------
                                      1 a                    val1
                                      1 b                    val1
                                      1 c                    val1
                                      2 d                    val2
                                      2 e                    val2
                                      2 f                    val2
                                      2 g                    val2
                                      3 a                    val3
                                      3 f                    val3
                                      4 aa                   val4
                                      4 bbb                  val4
                                      4 cccc                 val4

12 rows selected

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something similiar to this in the past. You need to create a function that accepts an input string and a separator and returns a dataset. If separator is ommited, then comma is assumed.

First create a new type that represents a table of strings:

```
create or replace type varcharTableType as table of varchar2(255);
/
```

Then create this function:

```
create or replace function splitString(
  allValues in varchar2,
  delim in varchar2 default ','
)
return varcharTableType
as
  str     varchar2(255) := allValues || delim;
  pos     number;
  dataset varcharTableType := varcharTableType();
begin
  loop
    pos := instr(str, delim);
    exit when (nvl(pos, 0) = 0);
    dataset.extend;
    dataset(dataset.count) := ltrim(rtrim(substr(str, 1, pos - 1)));
    str := substr(str, pos + length(delim));
  end loop;
  return dataset;
end;
/
```

Finally, call as:

```
select *
  from table(cast(splitString('a,b,c') as varcharTableType));

COLUMN_VALUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
---------------
a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
b                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

3 rows selected
```

To answer your specific case, you simply need to create a view that joins your table with this function table, as:

```
  create or replace view splitView as
    select yourTable.id, s.column_value as value
      from yourTable,
           table(cast(splitString(yourTable.value) as varcharTableType)) s;


  select * from splitView;

    id   value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    ---- ---------------
    1    a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    1    b                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    1    c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

    3 rows selected
```

I am not sure if this last query will work, as I don't have an Oracle machine right now, but hopefully should help you.