# Oracle split text into multiple rows

Tags: database, oracle, odp.net, varchar

Inside a varchar2 column I have text values like :

```
aaaaaa. fgdfg.
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccc
dddddd ddd dddddddddddd,
asdasdasdll
sssss
```

if i do *select column from table where id=...* i get the whole text in a single row, normally.
But i would like to get the result in multiple rows, 5 for the example above.
I have to use just one select statement, and the delimiters will be new line or carriage return (chr(10), chr(13) in oracle)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this, maybe (but it all depends on the version of oracle you are using):

```
WITH yourtable AS    (SELECT REPLACE('aaaaaa. fgdfg.' ||chr(10)||           
                        'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccc  ' ||chr(13)|| 
                        'dddddd ddd dddddddddddd,' ||chr(10)||
                        'asdasdasdll  ' ||chr(13)||
                        'sssss '||chr(10),chr(13),chr(10)) AS astr FROM DUAL)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ( astr, '[^' ||chr(10)||']+', 1, LEVEL) data   FROM yourtable   
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(astr) - LENGTH(REPLACE(astr, chr(10))) + 1
```

see: [Comma Separated values in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627916/comma-separated-values-in-oracle)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If i run your example i get the five rows + 6 more wich are null. If i run on my actual test data i get only the first line.i'm using oracle 10g

Comment: i think the problem is in the separators you used. the separator should be chr(10) OR chr(13), not both.

Comment: just replace one of the chanracters in the string so you are looking for a single delimiter....

Comment: This answer will break down if there is an empty line somewhere in your text. Reproduce: select REGEXP_SUBSTR ( 'line 1' ||chr(10)||chr(10)||'line 2', '[^' ||chr(10)||']+', 1, 2) from dual; -- This returns line 2 instead of NULL. Check here for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648653/regex-to-select-nth-value-from-a-list-allowing-for-nulls/25652018#25652018

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Kevin Burton contains a bug if your data contains empty lines.
The adaptation below, based on the solution invented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648653/regex-to-select-nth-value-from-a-list-allowing-for-nulls/25652018#25652018), works. Check that post for an explanation on the issue and the solution.

```
WITH yourtable AS    (SELECT REPLACE('aaaaaa. fgdfg.' ||chr(10)||           
                    'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccc  ' ||chr(13)|| 
                    chr(13)||
                    'dddddd ddd dddddddddddd,' ||chr(10)||
                    'asdasdasdll  ' ||chr(13)||
                    'sssss '||chr(10),chr(13),chr(10)) AS astr FROM DUAL)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ( astr, '([^' ||chr(10)||']*)('||chr(10)||'|$)', 1,  LEVEL, null, 1) data   FROM yourtable   
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(astr) - LENGTH(REPLACE(astr, chr(10))) + 1;
```